# Android - without any margin imageview

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I'm new to android and I want to make a menu consisting of 5 images **(no margin)**, even though change the android: ScaleType = "fitXY" adjusting the picture but let me margin, I need that an image next to each other

Link to images (code and layout)

[http://www.wsoft.com.ar/twillio-js/images/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-06-03%20a%20la(s)%2014.29.13.png](http://www.wsoft.com.ar/twillio-js/images/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-06-03%20a%20la%28s%29%2014.29.13.png)

[http://www.wsoft.com.ar/twillio-js/images/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-06-03%20a%20la(s)%2014.32.34.png](http://www.wsoft.com.ar/twillio-js/images/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-06-03%20a%20la%28s%29%2014.32.34.png)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callfree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView05"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/call_free" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView12"
        android:src="@drawable/my_flights"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_buscador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView09"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/callfree"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/buscador" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_flight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/my_flights" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_flight"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/settings" />
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some code, and ideally a screenshot of what the margins are actually looking like.

Comment: add the links there! thanks

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you added your layout text to the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Carl , add the code